# notepad++ autoclose quotes don't type quotes if it's the next character

Tags: plugins, notepad++, quote, auto-close

I'm using notepad++ and installed a few plugins, one of which auto-closes quotes (', ") as well as brackets ((, {). I've been on [codecademy.com](http://codecademy.com) to expand my knowledge on programming and noticed that if you type in quotes or brackets, it auto-closes it for you, but then if the quote is the next character in the editor, and you type in the quote, it won't actually type another quote. It'll just move to the other end of the quote. Is there a notepad++ plugin for this?

Comment: Which plugins have you tried? Hard to recommend one without knowing what you've used already.

Comment: I have webEdit, xBracketsLite, Zen Coding - Python, and textFX. XBracketLite will work the way I want, only if there is nothing between the quotes. But if I have characters between the quotes, it doesn't do what I want.